# How to run Android app with out using proxy to HttpClient

Tags: android, proxy, connection, httpclient, httpconnection

Am using the AuthScope & UsernamePasswordCredentials methods to set the proxy to all the http connections in my application. Is there any app which acts like a proxy for all the connections to avoid programatically setting proxy using above methods?

Even though i set the username and password in the Android settings proxy, but again its asking credentials in chrome and failed for all other apps.

Suggest some way to apply proxy for all the android apps.